# MyBatis Generator - collection properties (List<Object) in complex objects

Tags: java, mybatis, mybatis-generator

I am using MyBatis Generator to generate POJO objects which resemble my database structure. I would also like to have a list property in every object which has one to many relationships. Is this achievable ("C# alike class generation")?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

One to one/many relationships that generator need to acknowledge by using other tables are not supported by MyBatis Generator.

As stated in the [document](http://mybatis.github.io/generator/index.html):

> MBG seeks to make a major impact on the large percentage of database
>   operations that are simple CRUD (Create, Retrieve, Update, Delete).
>   You will still need to **hand code** SQL and **objects for join queries**, or
>   stored procedures.

Regarding the POJOs, MBG generates the following fields/classes:

> a class to match the primary key of the table (if there is a primary
>   key)
>
> a class to match the non-primary key fields of the table (except BLOB
>   fields)
>
> a class to include the BLOB fields of a table (if the table has BLOB
>   fields)
>
> a class to enable dynamic selects, updates, and deletes

Comment: Does this mean "Hibernate" in this case is better?

Comment: I think so. I was working with mybatis and i had the same issues.